# Opening and reformatting a text file in ipython

Tags: ipython

I am trying to open a text file below but my output is not what i want.
[image]

[image]

I need the date in the time tag column and pressure in pressure column.I will drop the rest of the columns.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

lol.. i figured it out
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6guUC.jpg)

Now i need to know how to merge the date and time to get a datetime column.